# Intersect and filter value of HTMLElement.prototype.dataset

Tags: javascript

I'm trying change the way `element.dataset` handles data, for example when submitted an empty string instead of storing an empty string and adding empty `data-foo` attribute it would simply remove the data from the database ( `delete element.dataset.foo` )

So instead of changing hundreds of lines in my code to call a function that would do this, I thought I'd do it globally by replacing `HTMLElement.prototype.dataset` with a proxy, with something like this:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.dataset = new Proxy(HTMLElement.prototype.dataset, {
  get(table, prop)
  {
    return table[prop];
  },
  set(table, prop, value)
  {
    if (value === "")
      delete table[prop];
    else
      table[prop] = value;

    return false;
  }
});

document.querySelector(".test").dataset.foo = "myData";
document.querySelectorAll(".test")[1].dataset.foo = "";
```

```css
.test
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1em;
}
.test[data-foo]::before
{
  content: 'dataset.foo: "' attr(data-foo) '"';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.test[data-foo=""]::before
{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Unfortunately, it fails with error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

at the very first line.

Any tips how to change `HTMLElement.prototype.dataset` to filter value before it's saved?

Comment: "*I'd do it globally by replacing `HTMLElement.prototype.dataset`*" - that's a really bad idea. "*… with a proxy*" - that is not possible. `.dataset` is a property, not an object.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the body.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, it's property, that's why I was thinking about replacing it with a proxy and forward any new values to original dataset. But even saving the original dataset via `originalDataset = HTMLElement.prototype.dataset` creates the error above

Comment: To be more specific, it is a property with a getter that **returns** a `DOMStringMap`. You would need to overwrite **the getter** with one that returns a proxy for the original map.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, but how do I forward value to original `DOMStringMap`?

Comment: Well first you'd need to get the original map for the particular element. None of your code handles `.dataset` being a getter.

Comment: @Bergi, sorry, how do I get "original map"? the "table" in my proxy is `HTMLElement.prototype.dataset`, wouldn't it be the "map"? And just so we are on the same page, the error occur during getting `HTMLElement.prototype.dataset` not replacing it.

Comment: Forget about the proxy for now. You want to overwrite `.dataset` so that it returns a different value (which later might be made a proxy, or anything else). You cannot do that using a proxy. And yes, accessing `HTMLElement.prototype.dataset` throws an exception because the getter needs to be accessed on an actual element, not on the prototype - notice that each element has its own dataset.

Comment: Basically what Bergi tells you (not) to do is https://jsfiddle.net/1gz7mtLy/ I.e, grab the descriptors on the proto, and overwrite the getter from there. But as they said that's "a really bad idea". Is it that hard to change that hundred lines of code? Your IDE certainly has a sed equivalent able to replace in batch. Changing how this property works means that when you'll include a library that expects the standard behavior, it might crash, and it might take time for you or even worst for your coworkers, to find why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Kaiido that is the solution I was looking for. Thank you! Would you mind post it as an answer. Although I've decided not to overwrite existing `dataset` property, but rather add a new `datasetAlt` property that would handle original `dataset`

Comment: Bergi almost got you there, and I don't want to advocate for modifying the protos this way. Feel free to self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments it's best not to overwrite existing prototypes, so I've decided  add new prototype that would handle the filtering:

```js
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "datasetAlt", {
  get: function()
  {
    return new Proxy(this.dataset, {
      get(table, prop)
      {
        return table[prop];
      },
      set(table, prop, value)
      {
        if (value === "" || value === undefined || value === null)
          return delete table[prop];

        if (value instanceof Object)
          value = JSON.stringify(value);

        table[prop] = value;
      },
      deleteProperty(table, prop)
      {
        delete table[prop];
      }
    });
  }
});


document.querySelector(".test").datasetAlt.foo = {fooObj:"fooData"};
document.querySelectorAll(".test")[1].datasetAlt.foo = "";
```

```css
.test
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1em;
}
.test[data-foo]::before
{
  content: 'dataset.foo: "' attr(data-foo) '"';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.test[data-foo=""]::before
{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

> Just for education purpose here is @Kaiido answer:
>
> ```js
> const dataset = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, "dataset");
> const datasetOrig = dataset.get;
> dataset.get = function()
> {
>   const dataset = datasetOrig.call(this);
>   return new Proxy(dataset, {
>     get(table, prop)
>     {
>       return table[prop];
>     },
>     set(table, prop, value)
>     {
>       if (value === "" || value === undefined || value === null)
>         delete table[prop];
>       else
>       {
>         if (value instanceof Object)
>           value = JSON.stringify(value);
>
>         table[prop] = value;
>       }
>     },
>     deleteProperty(table, prop)
>     {
>       delete table[prop];
>     }
>   });
> }
>
> Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "dataset", dataset);
>
> document.querySelector(".test").dataset.foo = {fooObj:"fooData"};
> document.querySelectorAll(".test")[1].dataset.foo = "";
> ```
>
> ```css
> .test
> {
>   border: 1px solid black;
>   height: 1em;
> }
> .test[data-foo]::before
> {
>   content: 'dataset.foo: "' attr(data-foo) '"';
>   display: inline-block;
>   width: 100%;
>   height: 100%;
>   background-color: lightgreen;
> }
>
> .test[data-foo=""]::before
> {
>   background-color: pink;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div class="test"></div>
> <div class="test"></div>
> <div class="test"></div>
> ```

Comment: "*I've decided add new prototype [property]*" - that's still not advisable for future compatibility, and if you have to rewrite your code anyway why not just use a proper wrapper/helper function?

Comment: Btw, the `get` and `deleteProperty` traps are unnecessary

Comment: @Bergi it was just simpler replace all instances of `.dataset` with `.datasetAlt` vs manually convert hundreds of `element.dataset.foo = "bar"` to `datasetAlt(element, "foo", "bar")`. P.S. thanks for the tips.